# Бот для автоматизации повторяющихся действий в игре

Tags: алгоритм, бот

Возникла идея создания бота для игры, для упрощения в ней рутинных действий. Сам являюсь студентом второго курса в сфере IT, есть некий базис, но знаний явно не хватает, поэтому обращаюсь за помощью.
Игра Simcity Buildit, бот будет с ней работать через эмулятор android на pc

Бот имеет приблизительно такую логику:

//производство

{

Найти неработающий завод

Открыть завод

Цикл: [Есть ли свободное место?]->(если да)[Заполнить свободное место выбранным товаром]->(если нет)[Перейти к следующему пункту]

Закрыть завод

}

//сбор готовой продукции

{

Найти готовый продукт

Собрать продукт

}

//выставление на продажу готовой продукции

{

Открыть биржу

Создать новый слот

Выбрать готовый продукт

Установить макс цену

Установить макс кол-во

Выставить на продажу

Закрыть

}

Что посоветуете для осуществления задуманного? Сессия сдана, время есть, желание тоже.
На каком языке вообще возможно написать данного бота? Какие утилиты осваивать и использовать?
Подойдет ли Autoit для этого?

Comment: Вот вам готовый урок по вводной в тему [игро-ботов](http://ngels.ru/bot-hack-clash-of-clans-bitmap-ocr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую вам посмотреть в сторону средств автоматизированного тестирования ПО. (AutoIt, Selenium, много их) В разных средствах это по-разному настраивается, но сводится к анализу пикселей, передвижению мышкой и нажатиям на клавиши. Если же вас интересует написание программы, то вам подойдёт любое средство разработки, которое может делать скриншоты, двигать и кликать мышкой, например Java .

Comment: Вот яву лучше руками не трогать, смотреть в сторону C#, там много наработок в этой области, например поискать на гитхабе тренеры Clash of Clans итд. Задача сама по себе не сложная, но требует постоянной оценки полученных битмапов, так что можно присматривать графическую библиотеку которая умеет продвинутое сканирование с разложением на rgb. Для начала мне кажется достаточно :)

Comment: почему сишарп? Тогда уж лучше Haskell или JavaScript)) Kакую продвинутую графическую библиотеку?? В core Java все это есть, если в сигара этого нет из коробки тогда зачем его брать? Наработки? Откройте гитхаб там полно чего угодно на любом языке.

Comment: Вопрос минталитета, все что касается Ява вм не есть хорошо, но тут у каждого своё мнение. Раньше с постоянными апгрейдами от сан явы было не просохнуть от переделок, оно просто не работало по разным поводам, чаще на предмет криков о секурности. Но уверен, явописцы не разделяют это мнение :)

Comment: Так а что не хорошо то?